# Does Time Bomb Reveal Invisible Allies?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was thinking about Zilean's Time Bomb ability, and I started thinking about fun ways to use it.  One such way would be to cast Time Bomb on an allied champion, while they're invisible.  (Eve, Shaco, Teemo, etc.)

I'm wondering though--technically if that explodes near an enemy champ, Zilean is the one dealing damage, not Eve/the invisible ally.  So what I'm curious about is whether or not the invisible ally will be revealed when "delivering" the Time Bomb.

(Obviously the enemy would know "something's up" if an invisible ally is detonated, even if not technically revealed.  I am just trying to find out if they will then become VISIBLE to the enemy)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stealth can only be broken by a stealthed champion performing an action that breaks stealth.

Though not *viable* by any means, before the sunfire cape's damage was a unique passive, it was fully possible to simply buy multiple capes and follow an enemy champion around while stealthed, relying on the damage to slowly kill them.

In this case, Time Bomb reacts the same as if you cast it on a ward - because the target is stealthed, the effect won't be visible, nor will it break stealth upon detonation. The enemy would just get a sudden burst of damage with no apparent cause.

Comment: So, from your response, I assume that you mean that the "ring" (explosion animation) will also be "stealthed" just like the character itself?  That is (potentially) a pretty powerful tactic...

Comment: Stealth is going to be totally remade soon fyi. RIOT have nerfed Twitch and Eve to near unplayable because stealth is a broken mechanic that dominates new players and low elo. So this question will need updating in the (near) future. See here for a more detailed discussion: http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/hp3vm/changes_to_stealth_coming_soon_some_morello_posts/

Comment: @Tux - yes. That's what I meant by "the effect won't be visible". Brush interacts the same way, actually - if an enemy nunu starts channeling his ult in the bushes, you will be slowed, but you won't see the particle effects of absolute zero unless you have vision inside the brush (and thus can through his 'stealth')

Comment: @danixd - yes, and I'm looking forward to it. But that shouldn't change the answer to this question.

Comment: I actually ran into this exact scenario last night, with my brother playing Zilean and having an Evelynn ally. It was quite amusing. It isn't necessarily the most potent use of your Mana, but it can be done to accumulate a fair amount of damage without the enemy noticing as explicitly.

Comment: @dani It's entirely possible that this may still be relevant. The stealth 'rework" as they've said has few details thusfar. It could simply be that stealth will be limited to Shaco-esque or Vayne-esque implementations, with severely reduced durations and long cooldowns.

Comment: @Grace Note It seems like more of a psychological influence.  Confusing the enemy or having them take damage AS IF from nowhere is a good way to have them scared early on.  (Especially since I'm not lvl 30/ranked yet--just a lowly lvl 20)

Comment: @Tux - for what it's worth, I find ranked games overrated.